# What does "look in the rearview mirror for flashing lights" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "look in the rearview mirror for flashing lights" mean? Does he mean **to see if the police are chasing him to take back everything he's got**?

> "I'm still here — on my third life, or maybe fourth," Bourdain said in 2016 of his rapid ascent to celebrity. "Who knows? I should've died in my 20s. I became successful in my 40s. I became a dad in my 50s. I feel like I've stolen a car — a really nice car — and I keep **looking in the rearview mirror for flashing lights**. But there's been nothing yet."

Source: [Anthony Bourdain quote](https://www.yahoo.com/entertainment/heroin-depression-getting-sober-anthony-bourdain-always-open-battling-demons-171835934.html)

Answer (score 2):

Literally, yes. The lights represent the police chasing him in order to apprehend him for the stolen car. However, he's using that figuratively. The stolen car represents something like his good life, his successes and celebrity. The lights and the police represent the end to that good life. He was expecting his good life to come to an end, but at that time, there had been nothing yet.

Comment: +1 Though I'd clarify, he compares his life to a stolen car. So apparently he believes, or has a nagging fear, that he doesn't deserve this good life. And so he's expecting that at any moment someone or some cosmic force will come and say, "hey, you don't deserve this" and take it away.

Comment: **Literally** would mean that he really is driving a stolen car and looking in the rear view mirror. I think that you mean **Metaphorically** - "not having real existence but representing some truth about a situation or other subject". https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/metaphorical?q=metaphorically

Comment: @JavaLatte Thanks, but I meant literally. That's what the phrase means literally, but that's not how he means it; he's using it figuratively (metaphorically).